# Sum of first $n$ perfect numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

I was working on a totally different problem relating to divisors recently, and I drifted on to this question: What is the sum of the first $n$ perfect numbers?

One pattern I have noticed regarding this question:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
6 + 28 &= 34 &= 2 \cdot 17\\
6 + 28 + 496 &= 530 \ &= 2 \cdot 5\cdot 53\\
6 + 28 + 496 + 8128 &= 8658\  &= 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 13\cdot 37\\
\vdots
\end{alignat*}
It seems at first that the sum of the first $n$ perfect numbers yields a number with $n$ distinct prime factors, but this pattern soon breaks down once we find $6 + 28 + 496 + 8128 + 33550336 = 33558994 = 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 2397071$. I don't know how this is helpful to the problem of finding the sum of the first $n$ perfect numbers, or whether it even has any significance to solving the problem. I'm just really curious as to how the sum of perfect numbers behave.

I recognize an important question to ask on the way to answering this question is whether or not there are infinitely many perfect numbers, and this is still an open question (although intuition implies that there are). Regardless, can we find a sum of the first $n$ perfect numbers or at least a satisfactory relation regarding this sum? Are there other patterns for this perfect number series? I'd appreciate your responses!

Comment: Are there any odd perfect numbers? Would come up ...

Comment: Even for even perfect numbers, you would need to be able to find an explicit form for the $n$th Mersenne prime

Comment: We know all EVEN perfect numbers upto a limit with several million decimal digits , so we can calculate the sums upto this limit assuming that there is no ODD perfect number. I do not expect very useful patterns apart from perhaps small prime factors. In fact, it is conjectured that infinite many perfect numbers exist since it is conjectured that infinite many Mersenne primes exist (we know currently about $50$).

Comment: Most mathematicians are convinced that there is no odd perfect number (although no proof exists) because there are many restrictions and it will be difficult to find a number satisfying them all, but of course we cannot rule them out. I suggest that you calculate the sums based on the known perfect numbers under the assumption that there are no odd perfect numbers.

Comment: Every third partial sum in the even series would be divisible by 3... Every ninth, divisible by 9 ...  Not much apart from that , that may help ... Always only has 1 factor of 2 ...

Comment: @Peter: We already know exactly $51$ Mersenne primes.  (Please see this [GIMPS page](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/).)

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris I know, I chose the formulation "about $50$" because another Mersenne prime might be found within the next days.

Comment: Additionally, the author does not want gaps and for the last few Mersenne primes, it is not known whether there are additional Mersenne primes upto that Mersenne prime. Currently, we know that the list upto the $47$ th Mersenne prime is complete.. But this can also change at every time.